# Unique Index created in the DB is not working with mongoose save() on node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I know many questions has been asked around this topic, however i can't seem to find a suitable and up-to-date answer.
On a new empty DB i used the following line throw `mongo` shell:

```
db.rest.createIndex( { "code": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Then i launched my node.js server. My schema looks like:

```
var restSchema = new Schema({code: String});
mongoose.model('rest', restSchema);
```

and the *save()* is done here:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var o = new (mongoose.model('rest'))({code: "uniuqeString"});
    o.save(function (err, o) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
});
mongoose.model('rest').find(function (err, rest) {
    res.send(rest);
});
```

Now, when ever this code runs, mongoose is inserting a new document to the db with `code:"uniqueString"` disregarding the unique index i have defined in advanced through *mongo shell*

Any thoughts why this might happen? Is it because i haven't defined the field as unique through mongoose's schema? If that is the case, i would like to predefine all indexes in the DB prior to the startup of the application and avoid index definition in the code.

Comment: Mongoose pluralizes your model name to make the default collection name. So those docs are going into the `rests` collection, not `rest`.

Comment: Amazing, thanks for the super simple solution, i guess I need to feel like the greenest newbe in the block....

Comment: No worries, that's probably the most common Mongoose error with new users. Widely acknowledged as a bad design decision, but we're stuck with it for backwards compatibility.